# Removing logo from a HTML page using 'Web Scraping'

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to remove a logo from a HTML page using 'Web Scraping' in Python. There's no issue with the code. It has been tested before, but I'm having an issue with selecting the HTML tag that contains the image source. Please guide me in selecting the tag.

Here's my code -->

```
def Histogram(file_path, rows, columns):
   
        df = file_reading(file_path, rows)
        column1 = columns[0]
        fig = px.histogram(df, x=column1).update_xaxes(
            categoryorder='total ascending')
        hist_path="templates/boxplot.html"
        fig.write_html(hist_path)
        
        links = ['<a href="https://plotly.com/" target="_blank" data-title="Produced with Plotly.js (v2.16.1)" class="modebar-btn plotlyjsicon modebar-btn--logo __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 132 132" height="1em" width="1em"><defs> <style>  .cls-0{fill:#000;}  .cls-1{fill:#FFF;}  .cls-2{fill:#F26;}  .cls-3{fill:#D69;}  .cls-4{fill:#BAC;}  .cls-5{fill:#9EF;} </style></defs> <title>plotly-logomark</title> <g id="symbol">  <rect class="cls-0" x="0" y="0" width="132" height="132" rx="18" ry="18"></rect>  <circle class="cls-5" cx="102" cy="30" r="6"></circle>  <circle class="cls-4" cx="78" cy="30" r="6"></circle>  <circle class="cls-4" cx="78" cy="54" r="6"></circle>  <circle class="cls-3" cx="54" cy="30" r="6"></circle>  <circle class="cls-2" cx="30" cy="30" r="6"></circle>  <circle class="cls-2" cx="30" cy="54" r="6"></circle>  <path class="cls-1" d="M30,72a6,6,0,0,0-6,6v24a6,6,0,0,0,12,0V78A6,6,0,0,0,30,72Z"></path>  <path class="cls-1" d="M78,72a6,6,0,0,0-6,6v24a6,6,0,0,0,12,0V78A6,6,0,0,0,78,72Z"></path>  <path class="cls-1" d="M54,48a6,6,0,0,0-6,6v48a6,6,0,0,0,12,0V54A6,6,0,0,0,54,48Z"></path>  <path class="cls-1" d="M102,48a6,6,0,0,0-6,6v48a6,6,0,0,0,12,0V54A6,6,0,0,0,102,48Z"></path> </g></svg></a>']
        
        replace_with = ""

        with open(hist_path, 'r+') as f:
                content = f.read()
                content = content.replace(links[0], replace_with)
                f.seek(0)
                f.truncate()
                f.write(content)          
   
                return hist_path
```

The plotly logo is what I want to remove. I copied the link via 'Inspect' --->

[image: Logo]

[image: Html code for the logo]

Debugging isn't showing me any error.

Comment: It might be handy for others to know what language you are using here

Comment: It's coded in Python.

Answer (score 0):

First, could you specify what error do you experience exactly?
And I cannot see where you're using web scraping for selecting tag, your code performs simple string replace operation. are you trying to remove logo from a remote webpage or just a local file? For local file your code looks fine (as soon as your `links[0]` string does really exist in a file content), but it's not web scraping. For live web page you'll need to use selenium method `execute_script('javascript snippet here')` to update html DOM. Please update your question properly so you could get more assistance

Comment: I'm removing the logo from a local file. I was told editing an HTML page is a part of web scraping. I'll remove the references to 'Web Scraping'.                                                             
My need is to know what portion of the HTML code that refers to the logo needs to be selected. What I copied is too big I don't think I captured it right.

Comment: So your code is not removing text or logo element? Removing whole <a> tag content should remove the logo. to copy full <a> tag from inspector it's handy to use menu option "Copy > Outer html". but I'd say passing the exact value of logo element to search for may be not ok as it may change dynamically. you should specify some reliable parts and then you can use regex (import re module): pattern = r'<a href="https://plotly.com/" target="_blank".*class="modebar-btn plotlyjsicon modebar-btn--logo.*<svg.*<title>plotly-logomark</title>.*</svg></a>'    content = re.sub(pattern, replace_with, content)

Comment: but if your text is removed and logo is still there it may be wrong element you're replacing. if in "Inspector > Edit as html" you remove the whole that <a> tag, is logo removed?